# Any holonomic robots available in Stage?

Tags: mobile-robot, ros, simulation, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi~I'm going to work with some robot formation methods in ROS. I want to do my experiments in Stage. However, the algorithm generates velocity vector (x,y）rather than (linear,angular) which is used by many nonholonomic robots like turtlebot. It's a bit tough to deal with diff-drive robot, which is not focused in my research.

So what I want is some kinds of ideal mobile robots in Stage to  do experiments for my formation method. But I'm new to stage and I've used only turtlebot in Stage before. I'd appreciate it if anyone can help me with some available kinds of robots in Stage or some useful packages in ROS. Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230188/any-holonomic-robots-available-in-stage?/) by [SilverBullet](https://answers.ros.org/users/20740/silverbullet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2016-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried changing `drive "diff"` to `drive "omni"` in your `.world` file for stage ?

See [the stage documentation for the position model](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/stage/html/group__model__position.html).

---

Originally posted by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) with karma: 883 on 2016-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SilverBullet](https://answers.ros.org/users/20740/silverbullet/) on 2016-03-27**:
Thanks! That's actually what I need. :)